# Как получать lac и cellid  через заданный промежуток?

Tags: android

Как получать lac и cellid сети через заданный промежуток, например 60 секунд?

Comment: а где проблема? у вас не получается узнать lac и cellid, или запустить повтор операции?

Comment: запустить повтор не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу получения lac, StackOverflow [подсказывает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276317/how-to-obtain-the-current-local-area-code-lac-of-the-handset-in-android):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellLocation cl = tm.getCellLocation();
if (cl instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
    GsmCellLocation gcl = (GsmCellLocation) cl;
    int lac = gcl.getLac();
    int cellID = gcl.getCid();    
}
```

Чтобы обновлять эти значения каждую минуту, можно использовать, например, [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Пример кода с `Timer` тоже легко [гуглится](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136942/):

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // здесь вы в бэкграунде, можете делать длительный операции
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // здесь у вас есть даже доступ к UI
                // вызывайте то, что надо, чтобы обновить интерфейс
            }
        });
    });
},
0L, // 0 миллисекунд до первого запуска
60L * 1000); // интервал - 60 секунд
```

Comment: а как это дело повторять?

Comment: т.е. в run() {} нужно засунуть всеь участок кода TelephonyManager tm...

 или только 

if (cl instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
    GsmCellLocation gcl = (GsmCellLocation) cl;
    int lac = gcl.getLac();
    int cellID = gcl.getCid();    
}

Comment: там где "// здесь вы в бэкграунде", нужно получать lac и cellid, а в части, где есть доступ к UI, обновлять интерфейс соответственно

Comment: @VladD Спасибо!